# Pass two queries with MondoDB and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm having a small issue which it seem I cant solve. I want to pass two queries to my add_people.ejs. The problem is that I can only pass one, but I have no idea how to pass the other query. For example:

```
var People = require("./models/people.js")
var Cities = require("./models/cities.js")

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    People.find({})
    .then(function(data){
        res.render("add_people", {data: data});
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
})
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server has started");
})
```

The above works perfectly, however, I also want to pass another query with a list of cities, but I have no idea to how pass that variable to my ejs.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thank you!

Comment: There must be a generic javascript dupe for waiting on multiple Promises but I'm struggling to find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` will allow you to wait for an array of promises to be resolved. The resolved value will be an array of those promises, resolved in the same order.

```
var People = require("./models/people.js")
var Cities = require("./models/cities.js")

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    Promise.all([
       People.find({}),
       Cities.find({}),
    ])
    .then(function(results){
        res.render("add_people", {
            data: { 
                people: results[0], 
                cities: results[1],
            }
        });
        console.log(results);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
})
```